# Heroku mLab configuration app still don't run

Tags: java, spring, heroku, mlab

I still cannot run mLab mongo DB on my app in heroku, I use MONGODB_URI to mlab in heroku, i need to add add-ons mLab to heroku or is it not necessary for my spring bott app? if it is why do I have to add credit card if sandbox is free?

Answer (score 0):

For your application to access the `MONGODB_URI` config variable, you must add an mLab add-on to your Heroku app or set the `MONGODB_URI` config variable manually.

Heroku requires a credit card for verification when you add an add-on (even if that add-on is free). You won't be charged for using free add-ons. See the Heroku documentation here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification.

If you do not want to add a credit card to Heroku, you can make a sandbox database directly on https://mlab.com/. mLab does not require a credit card for sandbox databases when you go through their website. You will need to manually set the `MONGODB_URI` config variable to the MongoDB connection string provided by mLab. You can see how to set config variables here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

You may also find the mLab add-on documentation helpful: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab

Comment: i have mLab DB and add conf vars URI from heroku app, but it dont works and I dont know how to solve this problem, cause heroku is black-box i cannot see any details from spring logs of my app why isnt connect to db etc. i tested hundred times on my localhost another server but on heroku is hard to find where can be problem

Comment: You can look at your application logs on Heroku by running `heroku logs` (more info here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)

Comment: after git push heroku master or mvn heroku:deploy spring app no errors but i see heroku error:  2018-02-16T19:04:11.317637+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pmsoft.herokuapp.com request_id=4d862f16-afb2-4fa4-a4c3-aebcbd286820 fwd="78.45.216.204" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: i add mongo uri direct to application.properties and it is OK only if I build whole war and deploy to heroku with heroku:deploy-war ............. with heroku:deploy or git push heroku master application never starts strange